# Recyclerview calls notifyItemChanged to cause a blank item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

`RecyclerView` calls `notifyItemChanged()` to cause a blank entry

I have a `RecyclerView` and it's every child item has a `RecyclerView`, when the dataset of `RecyclerView` in child item has changed (eg.some item inserted). I try to call the parent `RecyclerView`'s `notifyItemChanged()` to refresh it. But when I call that function, it will cause a blank item below.

```
mMessagesAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
```

when I call `notifyItemChanged()` for a position, there will be a blank item below, it can be visible, but there is no data, and it's all white.

Demo：https://github.com/zoodeveloper/NestBug

Comment: where do you insert the item?? `.notifyItemChanged()` is for updated existing items.

Comment: My layout is RecyclerView that it's every item inlude a RecyclerView, when I insert the item to the child RecyclerView,and I call the parent RecyclerView's  notifyItemChanged to refresh the item where the child RecyclerView in, the parent RecyclerView will cause a blank item below the item that I refreshed

Comment: With your comment, if you are inserting item then you need to call notifyItemInserted instead of notifyItemChanged, try this

Comment: no，I insert data to child RecyclerView,but every insert operations could cause the child RecyclerView's items re-ordered,so I chose to call the parent RecyclerView's notifyItemChanged to refresh the child RecyclerView whose data changed

Comment: @Wesley as this question is written, it is difficult to determine what the actual issue is. when having two `RecyclerView`, you might need to update the adapter's data accordingly, before calling to it's `.notifyItemChanged()`... then it should update the display properly; assuming it is the correct `position` (which might be a whole different one, depending which one `RecyclerView` it is).

Comment: refresh just child recyclerview. why are you refreshing parent

Comment: @Dharak Bhatt refresh just child recyclerview will also cause the parent RecyclerView a blank item below that item refreshd

Comment: @Martin Zeitler I have confirmed that the position I refreshed is correct,I have tried to call the child RecyclerView's notifyDataSetChanged(), But It will also cause the parent RecyclerView a blank item below that item refresed

Comment: @Wesley could you extend your question, with enough code to make it understandable? else I would almost have to vote to close it with "unclear what you are asking". see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have push the demo to github, can you help me solve the problem,thanks.
https://github.com/zoodeveloper/NestBug

Answer (score 2):

The `adapter.notifyItemChanged`() is used for refreshing an existing item. If you are adding a new item, then you should call `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, data.size())`

Comment: I have push the demo to github,can you help me,thanks.
https://github.com/zoodeveloper/NestBug

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting a new item you can use `notifyItemInserted (int position)`

> It is used to notify any registered observers that the item reflected
>   at position has been newly inserted. The item previously at position
>   is now at position position + 1.

Comment: I have push the demo to github,can you help me,thanks. https://github.com/zoodeveloper/NestBug

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider to call adapter.notifyItemChanged() from the main thread.

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override 
   public void run() { adapter.notifyItemChanged() } 
};
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```